# Is Security Context Holder Thread Safe

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using spring security. I was wondering if in a filter I set

`SecurityContextHolder.getcontext().setAuthentication(null)`

for one particular user who has at that instance suppose 100 api calls, would each of these calls securitycontextholder's authentication become null?

Answer (score 4):

SecurityContextHolder is threadsafe by default. So using this statement `SecurityContextHolder.getcontext().setAuthentication(null)` would actually be unsetting authentication on a per-thread basis.

Answer (score 2):

If you see the implementation of `SecurityContextHolder.getcontext()`, you will find  that `getContext()` is actually returning a thread safe object:

```
    final class ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy implements
            SecurityContextHolderStrategy {
        // ~ Static fields/initializers
        // =====================================================================================
        //.....


        private static final ThreadLocal<SecurityContext> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<SecurityContext>();

            public SecurityContext getContext() {
            SecurityContext ctx = contextHolder.get();

            if (ctx == null) {
               ctx = createEmptyContext();
               contextHolder.set(ctx);
            }

            return ctx;
        }
    }
```

As you can see in above code, `contextHolder` is actually the [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) object, which are by default thread safe variables. 
So by changing values using `SecurityContextHolder.getcontext().setAuthentication(null)` will not effect authentication object of other threads(Note:  Each & every web request are handled by separate threads).